# How to avoid mercurial obsolete warning on clients without evolve extension

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-phases

I currently work for a company that uses mercurial, but most developers use MQ instead of the new [evolve](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/) flow. Therefore, most users do not have the extension enabled.

Every time I push to the main repository, `.hg/store/obsstore` gets automatically pushed with the obsolete changesets. This is problematic because after that all users that do not have the extension enabled get the following message:

> obsolete feature not enabled but 33 markers found!

One solution, proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47209435/6748569) answer, involves deleting `.obsstore` locally, but that's not what I want, since I'm still working with `evolve` and that means I expect the obsolete changesets to remain hidden. Not only that, but obsolete markers and changesets should be available on the server repo so that we keep the benefits of using `evolve` such as intelligent conflict solving.

I'd expect a way to either not push the obsolete changesets to the server repo, or (the correct way) for the server to not push the obsolete data to  clients without `evolve` enabled.

Is this possible? If not, why not?

Comment: This post does not answer your question, but it is worth reading: [Please Stop Using MQ](https://gregoryszorc.com/blog/2014/06/23/please-stop-using-mq/)

Comment: Thank you, @andref. I had already read that entry, it makes very good points on why not to use MQ. Unfortunately, most people where I work do not agree, simply because there's a curve to learning a new paradigm.

Comment: @EullerBorges was evolve enabled on your server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a couple of workarounds (hacks) to this problem, since it looks like mercurial has no way to solve this issue as of the writing of this answer:

## Per-repository evolve extension

Remove the `evolve` extension from the `~/.hgrc` file, enable it on a per-repository basis, and then use SSH to point to the repository (in our case it is on NFS, which is the source of the problem).

That is, on your repository's `hgrc` you'd have:

```
# This is <repo>/.hg/hgrc
[paths]
default = ssh://localhost//path/to/origin/repo
[extensions]
evolve =
```

and on `~/.hgrc`:

```
[extensions]
# evolve =     => Disabled on purpose
```

---

## Removing obsolete markers using hooks

Just use a hook to remove the `.obspurge` file on your repository's `hgrc`:

```
# This is <repo>/.hg/hgrc
[alias]
obspurge = !echo "Purging obsolete markers" && rm /path/to/origin/repo/.hg/store/obsstore
[hooks]
post-push = hg obspurge
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use evolve locally but not exchange your obsmarkers, you can do it. I will tell you how but be aware that you will have the exact same set of problems as with using stripping  and rebase without evolve. If you push a previous version of a changeset and pushed the new version, the server will have the two versions at the same time.
If you want to use Evolve only locally you can add these lines in your config files:

```
[experimental]
createmarkers=True
allowunstable=True
exchangeopt=False
```

Comment: This, unfortunately does not solve the issue. The obsolescence markers are still pushed upstream with this configuration.

I think this is a major setback for evolve, since this means I have to manually delete obspurge every time (otherwise the tool is pretty much broken for other users).